# PHP String to run only after 5 min when page is loaded

Tags: php

I have a PHP page with the below code. I do not want to run the code directly after the page is opened. I want it to wait about 5 min and then run the SQL code.

```
<?php
                $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","****@","****");
                // Check connection
                if($link === false){
                    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }
                // Attempt select query execution

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ver_truck WHERE sla_client = 'Woodford' ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 1";

                $array = "";

                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        echo "<table width='100%' style='font-size: small'>";
                        echo "<tr align='center'>";
                        echo "<th  style='font-weight: bolder'>Reg</th>";
                        echo "<th  style='font-weight: bolder'>Model</th>";
                        echo "<th  style='font-weight: bolder'>Client</th>";
                        echo "<th  style='font-weight: bolder'>Action</th>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo "<tr align='left'>";
                            echo "<td align='center' style='color: red; font-weight: bold'>" . $row['reg'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['make'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['sla_client'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td align='center'><a href='/cases/verifications/verification_alarm_new.php?imei=" . $row['imei'] . "&type=" . $row['event_desc'] . "&reg=" . $row['name'] . "&event_id=" . $row['event_id'] . " '><button>Action</button></a></td>";

                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                        // Free result set
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    } else{
                        echo "No Current Verifications.";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                }

                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($link);
                ?>
```

Will the sleep() command in the beginning of this code prevent it from running for 5 minutes?

Comment: You are aware that PHP runs on the server before the webpage is rendered in the browser? You could send an ajax request after 5 mins to run that script though

Comment: no sleep()'ing for five mins will cause the browser to time out, instead of doing this in php, use js to then call the file after 5 mins with ajax

Comment: sleep(N) will make your request hang for N seconds. If you run `sleep(300)`, all that will happen is you'll be sitting there waiting 5 minutes for the page to load (or timeout). sleep is more appropriate for CLI. Honestly I don't see much of a purpose for it running on a web server.

Comment: Make an AJAX call to get the PHP data, and use `setInterval` with 5mins.

Comment: You can make frontend javascript do this work using `setTimeout()`